# How do I prevent the CSS NOT selector altering the parent element of a child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having a problem with the CSS **NOT** selector within the Jmpress.js slideshow framework.

It works well for making my inactive slides opaque. But it is also effecting the parent slide that my active child is stored within and so I am ending up with my child slide showing up as Opaque even though it is active.

I have included a Video of what is happening.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xvLMIQ2fSY

Example of how slides which fit in a Hierarchy, should be visible

That makes sense, but I guess there will be many parent/child relationships. It is like a menu hierarchy.

So if I am on a child slide, then I want it's parent (which becomes opaque thus effecting its children) to not get effected, though any other slides are set as opaque.

- A

  - A1
  - A2
- B

  - B1
  - B2
- C

If someone was viewing **B2** then I want **B** to visible, but I want **A** & **C** to be opaque.
I have include code below

Dave

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    /* Lots of CSS plus */
    .step:not(.active) {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="presentation">

        <!-- Any slide/step that is active shows while all others have an opacity of .3 -->  
        <div id="step_1" class="step" data--template="mytemplate" data-x="0" data-y="0" data-rotate="0" data-scale="0">
            <h2 class="StepTitle">My Slide</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="step_2" class="step" data--template="mytemplate" data-x="750" data-y="50" data-rotate="0" data-scale="0">
            <h2 class="StepTitle">My next Slide</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="step_3" class="step" data--template="mytemplate" data-x="1500" data-y="100" data-rotate="0" data-scale="0">
            <h2 class="StepTitle">David</h2>

            <!-- 
            When this slide: Step_4 becomes ACTIVE, its parent Step_3 becomes InACTIVE
            Because parent is inactive, Step 4 shows with an Opacity of 0.3, 
            when I really want the default Opacity of 1.0
            -->
            <div id="step_4" class="step" data--template="mytemplate" data-x="0" data-y="500" data-rotate="0" data-scale="0">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">You Tube</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jmpress.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function () {
            $('#presentation').jmpress();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Blow Blow

Answer (score 1):

You could use another css rule to match the active div inside inactive parent, and apply your 1.0 opacity to it, like so:

```
.step:not(.active) {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.step:not(.active) div.active {
   opacity: 1.0;
}
```

That should do what you want.

Comment: That makes sense, but I guess there will be many parent/child relationships. It is like a menu hierarchy.

So if I am on a child slide, then I want it's parent (which becomes opaque thus effecting its children) to not get effected, though any other slides are set as opaque.

A
 A1
 A2
B
 B1
 B2
C

If some one was viewing B2 then I want B to visible, but I want A & C to be opaque.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to offer a more general solution, just add another css rule that will set the correct opacity for your active divs inside inactive parents.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou Nelson for your response, the selectors you gave helped solve the problem but ultimately my problem needed to be resolved by following

http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

The Problem With CSS Opacity

The problem occurs when we add child elements to the html element that this code affects. All child elements will inherit the same opacity settings, even if you try to specify full opacity for all those elements (which would be too troublesome to do anyhow).

My code now has a wrapper object for the parent panel and the children sit outside of that wrapper panel but inside of the slide itself.

```
<slide id="step_3">
    <div class="panel">
        <a name="step3"></a>
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Multi Slides</h2>
    </div>

    <slide id="step_4">
        <div class="panel">
            <a name="step4"></a>
            <h2 class="StepTitle">You Tube</h2>
        </div>
    </slide>

    <slide id="step_5">
        <div class="panel">
            <a name="step5"></a>
            <h2 class="StepTitle">IFrame</h2>
        </div>
    </slide>
</slide>
```